# Resizing image - Cocoa - MAC OS X

Tags: cocoa, image, macos, resize

I am trying to write a small library that captures the screen shot and stores the image on the disk.

I was able to get the screen shot working and also to get the image stored on a disk. Now, I am not able to resize the image based on the specified height and width. Here is the code snippet:

```
int imageWidth = 200;
int imageHeight = 200;

CFStringRef keys[2];
CFTypeRef   values[2];
keys[0]   = kCGImagePropertyDPIHeight;
values[0] = CFNumberCreate(NULL, kCFNumberIntType, &imageHeight);
keys[1]   = kCGImagePropertyDPIWidth;
values[1] = CFNumberCreate(NULL, kCFNumberIntType, &imageWidth);


CFDictionaryRef options = NULL;
options = CFDictionaryCreate( NULL, (const void **)keys, (const void **)values, 2,
                               &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);

// Set the image in the image destination to be `image' with
// optional properties specified in saved properties dict.
CGImageDestinationAddImage(dest, imageRef, options);

bool success = CGImageDestinationFinalize(dest);
NSAssert( success != 0, @"Image could not be written successfully");
```

Please let me know if I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 3):

not sure, there could be a lot of things going on without seeing how you are making the CGImageRef, it would be tough to see a problem.
have you tried to use an NSImage, which is super easy to work with.

```
NSImage * img = [[NSImage alloc] initWithCGImage:imageRef size:NSZeroSize];
[img setSize: NSMakeSize(imageWidth,imageHeight)];

//do something with img;
[img release];
```

Failing that you could set some breakpoints, and make sure everything that you think is valid, really is.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `kCGImagePropertyDPIWidth` and `kCGImagePropertyDPIHeight` are meaningful options for `CGImageDestinationAddImage`. You need to create a new image with the given size and write *that* to the destination.

This can be done in several ways, but the simplest is probably going via `NSImage` as Grady suggests. You could also create a new `CGBitmapContext` of the desired size and pixel format, draw the existing image into it with `CGContextDrawImage`, then extract a new `CGImageRef` with `CGBitmapContextCreateImage`. It's a bit tedious, but should get you where you want to go.

Comment: You are right about those properties, you could poll for them, but thatCGImageDestinationAddImage only reads the destination properties which are `const CFStringRef  kCGImageDestinationLossyCompressionQuality` and
`const CFStringRef kCGImageDestinationBackgroundColor`

Answer (score 1):

This is doing my work, not sure whether this is efficient.

```
int imageWidth  = 200;
int imageHeight = 200;

CGContextRef    context = NULL;
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;
void *          bitmapData;
int             bitmapByteCount;
int             bitmapBytesPerRow;

// Get image width, height. We'll use the entire image.
size_t pixelsWide = imageWidth;//CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
size_t pixelsHigh = imageHeight;//CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);

// Declare the number of bytes per row. Each pixel in the bitmap in this
// example is represented by 4 bytes; 8 bits each of red, green, blue, and
// alpha.
bitmapBytesPerRow   = (pixelsWide * 4);
bitmapByteCount     = (bitmapBytesPerRow * pixelsHigh);

// Use the generic RGB color space.
colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(kCGColorSpaceGenericRGB);

// Allocate memory for image data. This is the destination in memory
// where any drawing to the bitmap context will be rendered.
bitmapData = malloc( bitmapByteCount );

// Create the bitmap context. We want pre-multiplied ARGB, 8-bits 
// per component. Regardless of what the source image format is 
// (CMYK, Grayscale, and so on) it will be converted over to the format
// specified here by CGBitmapContextCreate.
context = CGBitmapContextCreate (bitmapData,
                                 pixelsWide,
                                 pixelsHigh,
                                 8,      // bits per component
                                 bitmapBytesPerRow,
                                 colorSpace,
                                 kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);

// Make sure and release colorspace before returning
CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );

// Get image width, height. We'll use the entire image.
size_t w = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
size_t h = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);
CGRect rect = {{0,0},{imageWidth,imageHeight}}; 

// Draw the image to the bitmap context. Once we draw, the memory 
// allocated for the context for rendering will then contain the 
// raw image data in the specified color space.
CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, imageRef);

CGImageRef outImageRef = NULL;

outImageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage( context );
```